# solana program close, what about tokens owned by the program?

Tags: token

I want to do close one of my program. This program has an associated token address for USDC with some USDC on it.

If I delete it, will I get my USDC back ? Do I need to already have a USDC account to get the money back this way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you close your program prior to transferring the USDC from token accounts owned by a PDA of your program, you would lose the ability to access those tokens.

https://twitter.com/optifilabs/status/1564367455220219904